# Append node value to a particular node only instead of all matching nodes using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have 2 xml files, from source XML file i need to append matching node values into destination XML file.

I am able to do some extent using below code but if there are multiple nodes with same node name the values are getting appended to all matching nodes but actually i want to append to a particular matching node only.

For example,  node is in 3 places but i want to replace it at only one place which is inside the <org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.PipelineTriggersJobProperty>

when i used the below code it is appending into all 3 matching nodes.
I have tried append to a particular node but it is not working.

```
[XML] $destinationxmlfile = Get-Content "path/to/destinationxmlfile.xml"
[XML] $sourcexmlfile = Get-Content "path/to/sourcexmlfile.xml"

$nodeMapper = [ordered] @{
    #"//triggers" = "//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.PipelineTriggersJobProperty"
    "//triggers" = "//triggers"
    "//strategy" = "//strategy"
  }

foreach ($key in $nodeMapper.Keys) {
    $sourcenodevalue = Select-Xml -Xml $sourcexmlfile -XPath "$key" | ForEach-Object {$_.node.InnerXML}
    # node mapping
    Select-Xml -xml $destinationxmlfile -XPath $nodeMapper[$key] | ForEach-Object { $_.Node.InnerXML = $sourcenodevalue }
    $destinationxmlfile.Save($destinationxmlfile)
    #append <triggers> node to <org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.PipelineTriggersJobProperty>
    # this is not working
    #if ($key.contains('triggers') -and $null -ne $sourcenodevalue.SelectSingleNode("//triggers")) {
        #$nodes = $destinationxmlfile.SelectNodes('org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.PipelineTriggersJobProperty')
       # foreach($node in $nodes){ 
            #$node.AppendChild($destinationxmlfile.ImportNode($node, $true)) }
            #$destinationxmlfile.Save($destinationxmlfile) 
    #} 
}
```

Destination XMLFile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<flow-definition plugin="workflow-job@1316.vd2290d3341a_f">
  <actions>
    <org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.actions.DeclarativeJobPropertyTrackerAction plugin="pipeline-model-definition@2.2141.v5402e818a_779">
      <jobProperties/>
      <triggers/>
      <parameters/>
      <options/>
    </org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.actions.DeclarativeJobPropertyTrackerAction>
  </actions>
  <description/>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty>
      <strategy/>
    </jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty>
    <hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
      <parameterDefinitions/>
    </hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
    <org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.PipelineTriggersJobProperty>
      <triggers/>
    </org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.PipelineTriggersJobProperty>
  </properties>
  <definition class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowDefinition" plugin="workflow-cps@3697.vb_470e454c232">
    <sandbox>true</sandbox>
  </definition>
  <triggers/>
  <disabled>true</disabled>
</flow-definition>
```

Sourcexml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<com.cloudbees.plugins.flow.BuildFlow plugin="build-flow-plugin@0.10">
  <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty>
      <strategy class="hudson.tasks.LogRotator">
        <daysToKeep>10</daysToKeep>
        <numToKeep>-1</numToKeep>
        <artifactDaysToKeep>-1</artifactDaysToKeep>
        <artifactNumToKeep>-1</artifactNumToKeep>
      </strategy>
    </jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty>
  </properties>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers>
    <hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger>
      <spec>* * * * *</spec>
      <ignorePostCommitHooks>false</ignorePostCommitHooks>
    </hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger>
  </triggers>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders/>
 
  <buildWrappers/>
  <icon/>
</com.cloudbees.plugins.flow.BuildFlow>
```

Expected output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<flow-definition plugin="workflow-job@1316.vd2290d3341a_f">
  <actions>
    <org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.actions.DeclarativeJobPropertyTrackerAction plugin="pipeline-model-definition@2.2141.v5402e818a_779">
      <jobProperties/>
      <triggers/>
      <parameters/>
      <options/>
    </org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.actions.DeclarativeJobPropertyTrackerAction>
  </actions>
  <description/>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty>
      <strategy class="hudson.tasks.LogRotator">
        <daysToKeep>10</daysToKeep>
        <numToKeep>-1</numToKeep>
        <artifactDaysToKeep>-1</artifactDaysToKeep>
        <artifactNumToKeep>-1</artifactNumToKeep>
      </strategy>
    </jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty>
    <hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
      <parameterDefinitions/>
    </hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
    <org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.PipelineTriggersJobProperty>
      <triggers>
        <hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger>
        <spec>* * * * *</spec>
        <ignorePostCommitHooks>false</ignorePostCommitHooks>
        </hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger>
     </triggers>
    </org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.PipelineTriggersJobProperty>
  </properties>
  <definition class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowDefinition" plugin="workflow-cps@3697.vb_470e454c232">
    <sandbox>true</sandbox>
  </definition>
  <triggers/>
  <disabled>true</disabled>
</flow-definition>
```

Comment: Use more specific selectors: `"//triggers" = "//triggers"` -> `"//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.PipelineTriggersJobProperty/triggers" = "//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.PipelineTriggersJobProperty/triggers"`